# Can I use meander antenna as show in below pic

Tags: pcb-design, antenna, pcb-antenna

[image: Meander antenna]

I wondering will above antenna work properly or not because most of the PCB design layout antenna directed in right side & feed length remain unchanged.

As per as I know, feed length does not affect performance but it's width does.

Here is original antenna layout
[image]

Comment: You can, but the performance may or may not be what you want, depending on the materials, dimensions and frequencies involved, of which we have no knowledge.

Comment: Antennas are black magic. Computer simulation is the only way to know for sure. Depending on what you are dealing with, as well as the performance you need, you will have to include things like the case in the simulation.

Comment: That 'ground' on right side looks rather un-ground-y.

Comment: @JorenVaes is there any simulation software for this?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  it's properly ground but now I make it closer to feed line.